# Error Occured= CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException in sqlite when I am executing code

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-cursor, android-database

This is my SqlLite Query code where I am defining a method to get the category of color from the categories and returning it to the method as a String

```
public String getCategoryColor(String task) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select color from categories where title='"+task+"'", null );
    return res.getString(0);
}
```

Code

```
String color=db.getCategoryColor("Android developer");
Toast.makeText(list.this, color.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(color.equals("0xFF64FF0B"))
{
    taskt.setBackgroundColor(0xFF64FF0B);
}
else if(color.equals("0xFFFF0B4C"))
{
    taskt.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0B4C);
}
else if(color.equals("0xFF0B89FF"))
{
    taskt.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0B89FF);
}
```

Comment: share error logcat.

Comment: There is No results in the Cursor. You should check what moveToFirst() is returning (most likely false). Also you should use moveToNext(), not moveToFirst().

Comment: try logging `res.getCount();`. Looks like it is zero

Comment: I have'nt used mostToFirst() nor moveToNext() please share the edited code here .Thanks

Comment: yeah Thanks @Intellij

Comment: @AkshayRohilla Let me inform.

Answer (score 2):

**public abstract boolean moveToFirst ()** Move the cursor to the first row. This method will return false if the cursor is empty.

Returns whether the move succeeded.

```
  if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String id = cursor.getString(0);
    Log.v(id, id + "Color" );
    return color;
}
```

Comment: this makes problem when curson count is 0.

Answer (score 0):

No results in the Cursor. Also, you should use `moveToNext()`

```
public String getCategoryColor(String task) {

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select color from categories where title='"+task+"'", null );

String ret = null;
if(c.moveToNext()) {
    ret = c.getString(0);     
}
return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is perfect solutions:

1.At first check it's null and after it's size like below:

```
public String getCategoryColor(String task) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select color from categories where title='"+task+"'", null );
    if (res !=null && res.getCount > 0)
      {
         res.moveToFirst();
         return  res.getString(0);
       }
     else
      {
        return "";
      }    
}
```

2. And after Check like below:

String color=db.getCategoryColor("Android developer");

```
if(color.equals(""))
{
   // do your operation here if "" is occured.
}
else if(color.equals("0xFF64FF0B"))
{
    taskt.setBackgroundColor(0xFF64FF0B);
}
else  if(color.equals("0xFFFF0B4C"))
{
    taskt.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0B4C);
}
else if(color.equals("0xFF0B89FF"))
{
    taskt.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0B89FF);
}
```

Hope it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt have called

```
    cursor.moveToFirst()
```

before fetching the string thats why you were getting currsorindexoutofbound exception

Answer (score 0):

[**`CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

```
/**
 * An exception indicating that a cursor is out of bounds.
 */
public class CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException extends IndexOutOfBoundsException {
```

You should **`RECTIFY`** your **`getCategoryColor`** method.

```
public String getCategoryColor(String task) 
{

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String get_COLOR = "";
    String last_query = "SELECT color FROM categories WHERE title='"+ task+"'";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(last_query, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) 
    {

        get_COLOR = c.getString(0);
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return get_COLOR;

}
```

Comment: Hope this helps you.